# React Native KeyboardAwareScrollView doesn't work

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use the [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) library (0.2.7). It does absolutely nothing for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'

render() {
  return (
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
      <View>
        <TextInput placeholder='hi1' />
        <TextInput placeholder='hi2' />
        <TextInput placeholder='hi3' />
        <TextInput placeholder='hi4' />
        <TextInput placeholder='hi5' />
        <TextInput placeholder='hi6' />
        <TextInput placeholder='hi7' />
      </View>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is now advised to use [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview) instead. It is provided by React Native API. ;)

Comment: Thanks - I actually am using that right now, just seeing some weird functionality, so thought I'd experiment with the KeyboardAwareScrollView, but I'll just try and fix the quirks. Appreciate it.

Comment: Which weird functionality are you experiencing ?

Comment: I ended up fixing it, it was due to zIndex's. Thanks!

Comment: @whitep4nther, how about when you need a scrollview in that KeyboardAvoidingView? Got any working example code? It still seems very glitchy.

Comment: @RobinClaes Why does it seem glitchy ? With a ScrollView or whatever inside it should work as expected ;)

Comment: @RobinClaes oh yeah it's a bug, I even remember stumbling upon it. I even remember finding the line of code that made the bug, it's somewhere inside https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/cb6ec7c32141ef5bdde837d7f9d71b7adb83b751/Libraries/Components/Keyboard/KeyboardAvoidingView.js

Comment: I didn't spend time to ensure everything went alright but it's something you can fix easily, anyways it's a bug, you're supposed to use KeyboardAvoidingView

Comment: I can't achieve what I want with the KeyboardAvoidingView. It shrinks the View with height/padding, but instead I want the view to retain it's height and just scroll.

Comment: Link is not working.