# React Native: KeyboardAwareScrollView inside ScrollView doesn't work

Tags: javascript, react-native, github, scrollview

I am developing a Facebook type application where i have a problem in my **comments.js**. In this file i have **ScrollView** and **View** wrape in a **KeyboardAwareScrollView**.When i click a button it's **focus** on TextInput correctly.The problem is only the keyboard is open and the child component inside the **KeyboardAwareScrollView** is not scrolled to the last TextInputs where they can focused.

What i do i can **wrape** the ScrollView and View into into one **View** but did't any help.Then i apply multiple way's i think there is issue in my code.

This question is ask multiple time i read these

**[1.React-Native button press after textInput in Keyboard aware scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430116/react-native-button-press-after-textinput-in-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)**

**[2.React Native KeyboardAwareScrollView doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159729/react-native-keyboardawarescrollview-doesnt-work)**

**[3.Automatically scroll the view up when keyboard is shown in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481620/automatically-scroll-the-view-up-when-keyboard-is-shown-in-react-native)**

**[4.How to make your React Native app respond gracefully when the keyboard pops up](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580)**

but didn't meet my condition.

**Here is my code**

> ```
>      <KeyboardAwareScrollView style={{flex:1}} 
>                                 resetScrollToCoords={{ x:0, y: 0 }}>
>       <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewStyle}  
>                  keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
>           <Image/>
>           <List/>
>       </ScrollView>
>      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', height: 50 }} >
>         <Image
>           style={{ height: 40, width: 40, marginLeft: 20 }}
>           source={require('../../assets/plus.png')}
>         />
>
>           <View style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft: 20 }}>
>             <TextInput
>             autoGrow='true'
>             ref='myInput'
>
>             underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
>             placeholder='Type here to translate!'
>             onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
>           >
>             {this.state.text}
>           </TextInput>
>         </View>
>         <TouchableOpacity
>           onPress={() => {
>             this.CommentsApi()
>           }}>
>           <Image/>
>         </TouchableOpacity>
>       </View>
>     </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
> ```